# Consumir api rest react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Estoy investigando un poco React native.

Estoy consumiendo una api rest propia, pero mi problema viene, al mostrar los datos, no se muy bien como hacerlo, busco un poco lo que sería el equivalente de *ngIf y *ngFor en angular.
Alguien me puede ayudar a entenderlo un poco?

```
 postData() {
  const response =  fetch('**************', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
  console.log(responseJson);
})
.catch((error) => {
  //Error
  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  console.error(error);
});
```

}

Comment: Hola, ¿Tienes feedback? ¿La respuesta fue de utilidad? Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Se presenta un ejemplo mínimo de operación asincrónica con React Native, para consumir un **REST API endpoint**:

- Declarar variables de estado para los datos
- Ejecutar operación asincrónica API
- Devolver los datos con [Native Core Components](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react-native-components)

---

#### Declarar variables de estado para los datos

Se usa el hook `useState` para crear variables de estado, aqui se va asignar el resultado de la consulta al `endpoint` de `REST API`; `useState` se configura con una variable de estado `data`, una funcion handler `setData` y un valor inicial, en este caso se propone una arreglo vacío:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

---

#### Ejecutar operación asincrónica API

Luego, para ejecutar operaciones asincrónicas se usa el hook `useEffect`, aquí la configuración para que `postData` solo se dispare una vez (skip effects), al cargar el componente:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  postData()
},[]);
```

Después, dentro de la secuencia `fetch`, en la función de continuacion `then`, se asignan los datos provenientes de la API, en la variable de estado `data`, usando la función `setData`:

```
.then((responseJson) => {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
      //console.log(typeof responseJson);
      setData(responseJson.results);
    })
```

Al llamar a `setData`, se devuelve nuevamente todo el componente [(re-render)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712605/is-reacts-data-binding-really-one-way-it-seems-like-it-is-two-way).

---

#### Devolver los datos con Native Core Components

Finalmente, se devuelven los datos (render) dentro del método `return`, aquí se muestra el uso del método `map` de JS; la función anónima de `map` se configura con un `return` implícito, pues el objetivo es devolver los elementos en "Render time".

Suponiendo que el endpoint regresa un array `results`, dentro del cual hay parámetros como `name` e `image`:

```
return (
      <ScrollView>
      {data.map((element)=>(
        <View>
          <View>
            <Image src={element.image} />
            <Text>{element.name}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
      </ScrollView>
    );
```

Aqui se usan Native Core Components como `ScrollView`, `View`, `Image` y `Text` para envolver los datos que se van a mostrar en la **User Interface UI** dentro del método `render`, en vez de las etiquetas/elementos DOM, pues son layouts para dispositivos móviles.

---

#### Ejemplo

El componente completo puede quedar codificado de la siguiente forma:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView , View , Text, Image } from 'react-native';

function App(){
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    //URL: la URL de tu endpoint API
    function postData() {
      const response =  fetch(URL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
      //console.log(typeof responseJson);
      setData(responseJson.results);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      //Error
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      console.error(error);
    });
    }
  
    useEffect(()=>{
      postData()
    },[]);
  
    //console.log(data);
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      {data.map((element)=>(
        <View>
          <View>
            <Image src={element.image} />
            <Text>{element.name}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

---

#### Notas de campo

> busco un poco lo que sería el equivalente de *ngIf y *ngFor en angular.

- Nótese que en `ReactJS` se pueden usar métodos de **JS**, en este caso en vez de `ngFor`, se usa `map` con iterables.
- Por lo tanto, un `if` o un **operador condicional ternario** de **JS** pueden sustituir a `ngIf`.

[Ejemplos a nivel básico React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react)

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.